# How to share angular 2 component (google maps) on different pages?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 & angular 2

I have created google-map component ND initialized it on the home screen,  i need a way to present this map on another pages.

what is the best way to pass or create new google map on multiple pages?
Is there a way to use the same instance of that map?

GoogleComponent.ts:

```
export class GoogleMapComponent{
  private createMap(){
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: this.Position
  });
}
```

home.ts:

```
    <div class="inner-container">
        <google-map></google-map>
</div>
```

page2.ts:

```
  <div class="inner-container">
      <google-map></google-map>
  </div>
```

**need to get this map on page 2,3,4,etc... as well, any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use Angular2 dependancy injection to inject your injectables  `annotated with @Injectable()` (usually services)  to other pages and get the injected instance in the constructor of the page.

you can control if you want to create a new instance every time or use the same singleton for the injetction and use a provider to do this.
This thread contains some useful information
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/injecting-service-into-tabs-ionic-2/51813/2

As a sidenote. [this project](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/) is a nice implementation of angular2 google map component

Comment: But how can i inject an element to the dom?

Comment: take a look into @ViewChild